# Oracle - select statement to pivot and change how data is displayed

Tags: oracle, pivot, union

I currently have data in an Oracle tabel that looks like this:

```
Person_ID   Fieldname              Fieldnumber
123         2016 Salary            50000
123         2015 Salary            45000
123         2014 Salary            40000
123         2016 Vacation Days     5
456         2016 Salary            50000
456         2016 Vacation Days     5
789         2016 Salary            90000
789         2016 Vacation Days     5
```

I would like write a select statement to Pivot and change the display of the data so it looks like this:

```
Person_ID    Fieldname      2016         2015         2014
123          Salary         55000        45000        40000
123          Vacation Days  5  
456          Salary         50000      
456          Vacation Days  5                                  
789          Salary         90000                                        
789          Salary         5
```

How can I do this so that if new field names are added, my SQL will automatically add new columns when I run it? Is there a way to do this with pivot or should I use union or another function that I am not familiar with?

The pivot I usually run looks like this but I don't think the concept will work in this scenario:

```
select *
  from cust_matrix
unpivot
(
  state_counts
    for state_code in ("New York","Conn","New Jersey","Florida","Missouri")
)
order by "Puchase Frequency", state_code
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your last remark; you usually run `UNPIVOT` to pivot data? Does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be confused by the fact that there are two columns that are not part of the "pivot", in your case `person_id` and `fieldname`. Pivoting works exactly the same way.

Notes - your input table is obviously missing a column name (for year) - which better not be Year, a reserved word in Oracle. I used `yr` in my sample inputs. You also have a typo in the output (where did 55000 come from, for year 2016 and person_id = 123? The inputs had 50000).

And, you can have 2016 as a column name, but it would have to be double-quoted and it may cause unexpected problems later. Best to use standard column names - which, in particular, can't begin with a digit. I used `y2016` etc.

```
with 
     inputs ( person_id, yr, fieldname, fieldnumber ) as (
       select 123, 2016, 'Salary'       , 50000 from dual union all
       select 123, 2015, 'Salary'       , 45000 from dual union all
       select 123, 2014, 'Salary'       , 40000 from dual union all
       select 123, 2016, 'Vacation Days',     5 from dual union all
       select 456, 2016, 'Salary'       , 50000 from dual union all
       select 456, 2016, 'Vacation Days',     5 from dual union all
       select 789, 2016, 'Salary'       , 90000 from dual union all
       select 789, 2016, 'Vacation Days',     5 from dual
     )
-- end of test data; actual solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select person_id, fieldname, y2016, y2015, y2014
from   inputs
pivot ( max(fieldnumber) for yr in (2016 as y2016, 2015 as y2015, 2014 as y2014) )
order by person_id, fieldname
;

PERSON_ID  FIELDNAME      Y2016  Y2015  Y2014
---------  -------------  -----  -----  -----
123        Salary         50000  45000  40000
123        Vacation Days      5     
456        Salary         50000     
456        Vacation Days      5     
789        Salary         90000     
789        Vacation Days      5
```